# Looking up data in an Oracle (12.1) table using keys from a text file

Tags: join, text, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with approximately 8 million rows in it. It has a uniqueness constraint on a column called Customer_Identifier. This is a varchar(10) field, is not the primary key, but is unique.

I wish to retrieve some customer rows from this table using SQL Developer. I have been given a text file with each record containing a search key value in the columns 1-10. This query will need to be reused a few times, with different customer_identifier values. Sometimes I will be given a few customer_identifier values (<1000 of them). Sometimes many (between 1000 and 10000 of them). For the times when I want fewer than 1000 values, it's pretty straightforward to use an IN clause. I can edit the text file to wrap the keys in quotes and insert commas as appropriate. But SQL developer has a hard limit of 1000 values in an IN clause.

I only have read rights to the database, so creating and managing a new physical table is out of the question :-(.

Is there a way that I can treat the text file as a table in Oracle 12.1, and thus use it to join to my customer table on the customer_identifier column?

Brgds
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can treat a text file as an external table. But you may need DBA assistance to create a new directory, if you don't have access to a directory defined in the database.

Thanks to [Oracle Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i)

```
**Create a directory object pointing to the location of the files.**

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ext_tab_data AS '/data';

**Create the external table using the CREATE TABLE..ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL syntax. This defines the metadata for the table describing how it should appear and how the data is loaded.**

CREATE TABLE countries_ext (
  country_code      VARCHAR2(5),
  country_name      VARCHAR2(50),
  country_language  VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      country_code      CHAR(5),
      country_name      CHAR(50),
      country_language  CHAR(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Countries1.txt','Countries2.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

**Once the external table created, it can be queried like a regular table.**

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   countries_ext
  3  ORDER BY country_name;

COUNT COUNTRY_NAME                 COUNTRY_LANGUAGE
----- ---------------------------- -----------------------------
ENG   England                      English
FRA   France                       French
GER   Germany                      German
IRE   Ireland                      English
SCO   Scotland                     English
USA   Unites States of America     English
WAL   Wales                        Welsh

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```